# Wrong (most probably) THIS context

Tags: javascript

I have  problem with (most probably) the context of **this**:
Im new in JS and think more like c++ guy.
Please, see the code:

*controller.js* :

```
function CController(){ ... 
    this.myCanvas = new CCanvas(this);
}
CController.prototype.resize() {...}
```

*canvas.js* :

```
function CCanvas(_mainController){
    var controller = _mainController;
}
CCanvas.prototype.myEvent(){
    this.controller.resize();  // <--- here!
}
```

I get the error at mentioned line that controller is undefined.
how can it be corrected?

Comment: I'm surprised that you got *one working* code and one *non-working*, but you don't see the pattern. Hint: `this.controller = /*...*/`

Comment: but is it possible to not declare controller with 'this' prefix so it wont be a property that is accessible from outside this function?

Comment: sure but then trying to access it in another method won't work.

Comment: Why would you want to not declare it as an object property under the pretense that it *won't be accessible* outside that function when you **are** using it outside that function to start with? Last I checked, `myEvent()` isn't the constructor of the class (= not the function).

Comment: Added a way to do so just in case in my answer. I strongly recommend you to look at the things you sacrifice for this, however. It's there purely to highlight the issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely not a scoping issue. Assuming your `_mainController` is *actually* a controller (which I'll add in the version I'm about to show you), your problem is that in the constructor of `CCanvas`, you're assigning `var controller`, not `this.controller`. This in turn causes `controller` to be dropped (as `var` is the keyword for a local variable, after all.

```
function CCanvas(_mainController){
    if (!(_mainController instanceof CController)) throw "Not a controller";
    this.controller = _mainController;
}
```

This should work. And it prevents you from supplying a non-controller.

If you really want to stick to your guns as in the comments and having the variable *not* on the class but still in lexical scope, do this:

```
var CCanvas = function(_mainController) {
  var outputCCanvas = function(){
  };
  outputCCanvas.prototype.myEvent = function(){
     console.log("Event");
  }
  return outputCCanvas;
};
```

The level of indirection on this one is crazy, and you lose a *ton* of good stuff doing it:

- It'll be impossible to do `instanceof` checks on `CCanvas`, as each and every instance is generated dynamically every time you call the method
- Oh, yeah, your instantiation changes. Now, you're doing `new (CCanvas(_mainController))()`, since `CCanvas` is now a method returning a class